# Calling get_position on KinematicBody2D causes a get_global_transform error

Tags: unit-testing, godot, gdscript

## Summary

I'm trying write a unit test using [Gut](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut) for my `player` in [gdscript](/questions/tagged/gdscript) but calling `get_position()` on the `player` (a [KinematicBody2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html)) is causing the following error:

```
ERROR: get_global_transform: Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returned: get_transform()
   At: scene/2d/canvas_item.cpp:467.
ERROR: body_test_motion: Condition "!body->get_space()" is true. Returned: false
   At: servers/physics_2d/physics_2d_server_sw.cpp:1046.
ERROR: get_global_transform: Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returned: get_transform()
   At: scene/2d/canvas_item.cpp:467.
ERROR: body_test_ray_separation: Condition "!body->get_space()" is true. Returned: false
   At: servers/physics_2d/physics_2d_server_sw.cpp:1058.
```

### Expectation

I was expecting that after `_physics_process()` I would be able to get the updated `position` of my `player` but it returns `Vector2(0, 0)`.

## Resources

This is my first time using GDScript so I have been using a mixture of the following resources in an attempt to write this first test:

- [8-way movement](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/2d_movement.html#way-movement)
- [TDD and PONG Episode 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF2gPF69Dc4&t=3s)
- [GUT Command-line](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/wiki/Command-Line)
- [Stubbing Input Class](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/issues/171)

### Failed solutions

I think I may need to make the `player` a child of something else but I'm unsure how to do this within my test.

I tried searching the [Gut issues](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/issues?q=is%3Aissue+child) on how to use `add_child()` within a test but I couldn't find an answer.

I also tried making the `player` a child of an `Area2D` but that didn't seem to work either:

```gdscript
var player := Player.new(input)
var area := Area2D.new()
area.add_child(player)
```

## Code

This is the code that is causing the error when calling `gut` from the command line:

`test/unit/actors/test_player.gd`

```gdscript
extends "res://addons/gut/test.gd"

func test_can_create_player() -> void:
    var input = MockInput.new()
    var player := Player.new(input)
    
    assert_not_null(player)

func test_can_move_player_up() -> void:
    var input = MockInput.new()
    input.press("ui_up")

    var player := Player.new(input)

    simulate(player, 1, .1)
    assert_eq(player.get_position(), Vector2(200, 0))
```

`test/mock_input.gd`

```gdscript
class_name MockInput

var _pressed: Dictionary = {}

func press(key: String) -> void:
    _pressed[key] = true

func release(key: String) -> void:
    _pressed[key] = false

func is_action_pressed(key: String) -> bool:
    if _pressed.has(key):
        return _pressed.get(key)

    return false
```

`entities/actors/player.gd`

```gdscript
extends KinematicBody2D

class_name Player

export var speed: int = 200

var _input: Object = Input
var _velocity: Vector2 = Vector2()

func _init(input: Object = Input):
    _input = input

func _physics_process(_delta: float) -> void:
    _velocity = Vector2()
    
    if _input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        _velocity.x += 1
    if _input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        _velocity.x -= 1
    if _input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        _velocity.y += 1
    if _input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        _velocity.y -= 1

    _velocity = _velocity.normalized() * speed
    _velocity = move_and_slide(_velocity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that worked for my purposes (I'm a little bit annoyed that I missed this the first time).

As I suspected, the `player` needs to be a child of another `Node`.

In the `test/unit/actors/test_player.gd` after the `player` variable has been defined it can be added as a child of the test itself using:

```gdscript
self.add_child_autofree(player)
```

With the complete unit test as the following:

```gdscript
func test_can_move_player_up() -> void:
    var input = MockInput.new()
    input.press("ui_up")

    var player := Player.new(input)
    self.add_child_autofree(player)

    simulate(player, 1, 0)
    assert_eq(player.get_position().round(), Vector2(0, -30))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you `!is_inside_tree()`. The problem is not -only- that the node does not have a parent. The problem is that it is not inside a `SceneTree`.

You can create your own instance of `SceneTree`. You can even extend it. For example, this would work:

```
var node := KinematicBody2D.new()
    
var tree := SceneTree.new()
tree.get_root().add_child(node)
yield(tree, "idle_frame")
print(node.get_global_transform())
```

---

Now, about Gut… Your tests will be running inside a `SceneTree`. Thus, you can add the nodes you want to test as children. Just remember to do proper teardown (remove the nodes). Because Gut will not do it for you, and if children nodes linger from one test to another, then they aren't units anymore.

**Addendum**: You can use `add_child_autofree` to add a child, and also queue it for freeing right after the test ends.

---

*The rest of the answer is me going over how Gut runs tests to confirm they run inside a SceneTree.*

The file [`gut_cmdln.gd`](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut_cmdln.gd) is actually an extended `SceneTree`. It will load `gut.gd` ([here](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut_cmdln.gd#L43)) and add it as a node to itself ([here](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut_cmdln.gd#L273-L274)).

In turn, [`gut.gd`](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut.gd) is in charge of running the tests, which is handled by [`_test_the_scripts`](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut.gd#L801). What I want you to look is [this](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut.gd#L842-L844):

```
        var test_script = the_script.get_new()
        var script_result = null
        _setup_script(test_script)
```

There `the_script` is a [`TestScript`](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/test_collector.gd#L27) object. The `get_new` call will return an instance. And [`_setup_script`](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut.gd#L596)…

```
func _setup_script(test_script):
    test_script.gut = self
    test_script.set_logger(_lgr)
    add_child(test_script)
    _test_script_objects.append(test_script)
```

Will add it as child (of `gud.gd`).

Afterwards `_test_the_scripts` will go into a loop ([here](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut.gd#L868)) and call [`_run_test`](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut.gd#L700) or [`_run_parameterized_test`](https://github.com/bitwes/Gut/blob/master/addons/gut/gut.gd#L678) (which calls `_run_test`) to actually run the test. And `_run_test` will use `call` on the instance to run the test method (with extra steps).

Huzza! Your tests will be running in a custom `SceneTree`.